# How I do read the last line of a file?

Tags: c, file

I have a file like this from which I need some values from its last line. This is the file:

```
XFOIL Version 6.96

Calculated polar for: pane 

1 1 Reynolds number fixed Mach number fixed 

xtrf = 1.000 (top) 1.000 (bottom) 
Mach = 0.000 Re = 0.100 e 6 Ncrit = 4.000

alpha CL CD CDp CM Top_Xtr Bot_Xtr
------ -------- --------- --------- -------- -------- --------
0.000 0.3882 0.01268 0.00440 -0.0796 0.6713 1.0000
```

What I want to do is to read the values of `alpha`, `CL` and `CD` located in the last line.

I use this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main ()
{
  FILE * pFile;
  FILE * test1;

   char ch;
   double alpha,lift,drag;
   int i;

   pFile = fopen("save.txt","r");
   test1 = fopen("test1.txt","w");

   fseek ( pFile , 434 , SEEK_SET );

  while( ( ch = fgetc(pFile) ) != EOF ){
      fputc(ch, test1);
  }

  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {

  fscanf(test1, "%lf  ",&alpha);
  fscanf(test1, "%lf ",&lift);
  fscanf(test1, "%lf",&drag);

  }

  printf("alpha = %lf  cl = %lf   cd = %lf",alpha,lift,drag);

  fclose(test1);
  fclose ( pFile );
  return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance...

```
Guys thank you all for your answers what i forgot
```

to mention is that it prints out that alpha = 0.00000 
cl = 0.00000 cd = 0.00000 which actually are non zero but
 0.000 0.3882 0.01268 respectivelly...!!

Comment: What's not working as expected?

Comment: Read the values from every line into the same variables. Since the last line comes last, the variables will end up with the values from the last line.

Answer (score 3):

```
   pFile = fopen("save.txt","r");
   test1 = fopen("test1.txt","w");
```

You are opening `save.txt` for reading, and `test1.txt` for writing.

```
   fseek ( pFile , 434 , SEEK_SET );

  while( ( ch = fgetc(pFile) ) != EOF ){
      fputc(ch, test1);
  }
```

You are now skipping to character 434 in `save.txt`, and then reading the rest of the file, printing each character out into `test1.txt`.

```
  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {

  fscanf(test1, "%lf  ",&alpha);
  fscanf(test1, "%lf ",&lift);
  fscanf(test1, "%lf",&drag);

  }
```

You are now trying to read from `test1.txt`, but it is open for writing, and the current position is at the end of the file. If you want to read it, you will need to either close it and open it for reading, or open it read-write (`fopen(..., "rw")`) up above and then reset the current position to the beginning of the file before starting to read (it is undefined what will happen if you don't do that).

In fact, you shouldn't need to skip to a byte offset, copy the last line into a different file, and then read that new file. You can just read the last line directly from the original file. No need for that loop that reads from one file into another; just run your `scanf()` on the original file.

Remember to check your function calls for errors. The `scanf()` calls that you made probably returned an error. You can check for an error with `ferror(file)`, and get the actual error message with `strerror(errno)`.

Comment: Guys thank you all for your answers what i forgot to mention is that it prints out that alpha = 0.00000 cl = 0.00000 cd = 0.00000 which actually are non zero but 0.000 0.3882 0.01268 respectivelly...!!

Comment: Did you try taking the suggestions I made? Did they help? Can you show the new version, and indicate what is going wrong with it?